# Can ngClass use ternary operator in Angular 2?

Tags: typescript, angular

In Angular 1, the code below works well.

```
<div ng-class="$varA === $varB ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'">
```

But when I try to do similar thing in Angular 2. It does not work.

I already added `directives: [NgClass]`

```
<div [ngClass]="varA === varB ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'">
```

How should I write in Angular 2, thanks!

**EDIT: It was my mistake, I accidentally added `{` `}` to the whole `varA === varB ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'`. So ngClass still can use ternary operator in Angular 2.**

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Yes. What you wrote works:

```
<div [ngClass]="varA === varB ? 'css-class-1' : 'css-class-2'">
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/C6dNlDiynghdDFNZ1zSJ?p=preview)

The result of the expression on the the right-hand side has to evaluate to one of the following:

- a string of space-delimited CSS class names (this is what your expression returns)
- an Array of CSS class names
- an Object, with CSS class names as keys, and booleans as values

Maybe you had some other error in your code?

Comment: Thanks, this is weird, mine actually is `[ngClass]="{message.userId === user._id ? 'message-mine' : 'message-other'}"`, this does not work. But this works `[ngClass]="{'message-mine':message.userId === user._id, 'message-other':message.userId !== user._id}"`

Comment: @HongboMiao, the first one should not have `{` and `}`.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The original question was about using the ternary operator ?

Answer (score 23):

```
<div [ngClass]="{'css-class-1':varA === varB, 'css-class-2': varA !== varB}">
```

See also https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just fix a typo, it is `!==` instead of `!===`

Comment: There's also `<div [class.css-class-1]="varA === varB" [class.css-class-2]="varA !== varB">`. As far as I can tell it's personal preference about which way you want to do it though.

Comment: Docs return 404

Comment: Thanks @Corey I was wondering how to use ternary without else because you cant use statement if, only expression. This worked!

Answer (score 10):

You can try the followings.....

For ternary operator use:

```
[ngClass]="condition1==condition2?'class-1':'class-2'"
```

For multiple condition use:

```
[ngClass]="{'class-1':condition1==condition2, 'class-2': condition3==condition4}"
```

thnks...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
<div class="css-class-3 css-class-4" [ngClass]="{'css-class-1': varA === varB, 'css-class-2': !(varA === varB)}">
```

this worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

maybe this example, will make it clearer:

```
<div [ngClass]="salesVolume <= 55_000 ? 'bg_green' : 'bg_red' " >
```

bg_green and bg_red are 2 class styles defined in your style.css file