# setElementClass for multiple classes in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to add multiple class after I click an icon in angular2

This is my code:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Renderer} from 'angular2/core';
import {CourseService} from './courses.service';
import {AutoGrowDirective} from './auto-grow.directive';

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `<i (click)="onclick($event)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <h3>Courses</h3>
                {{title}}
                <input type="text" autoGrow/>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
                        {{course}}
                    </li>
                </ul>`,
    providers: [CourseService],
    directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    title:string = "List of course";
    courses;

    constructor(courseService:CourseService, private el:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }

    onclick($event) {
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty', true);
    }
}
```

But when I click on the icon my browser console throws this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
```

I figured it's because a space between classes, what I couldn't figure myself is how do I add multiple classes in an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `this.renderer.setElementClass(...)` for each class individually and set the `isAdd` parameter to `true`

```
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'glyphicon', isAdd: true);
this.renderer.setElementClass(this.el.nativeElement, 'glyphicon-star-empty', isAdd: true);
```

(not tested)

**update**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `<i (click)="onclick($event)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></i>
                <h3>Courses</h3>
                {{title}}
                <input type="text" autoGrow/>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
                        {{course}}
                    </li>
                </ul>`,
    providers: [CourseService],
    directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    title:string = "List of course";
    courses;

    constructor(courseService:CourseService) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }


    @HostBinding('class.glyphicon') 
    @HostBinding('class.glyphicon-star-empty') 
    _isGlyphIcon:boolean = false;

    onclick($event) {
        this._isGlyphIcon = true;
    }
}
```

**update2**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `<i (click)="onclick($event)" [ngClass]="_iconClasses"></i>
                <h3>Courses</h3>
                {{title}}
                <input type="text" autoGrow/>
                <ul>
                    <li *ngFor="#course of courses">
                        {{course}}
                    </li>
                </ul>`,
    providers: [CourseService],
    directives: [AutoGrowDirective]
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    title:string = "List of course";
    courses;

    constructor(courseService:CourseService) {
        this.courses = courseService.getCourses();
    }

    _iconClasses:string[] = ['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-star'];

    onclick($event) {
      this._iconClasses = ['glyphicon', 'glyphicon-star-empty'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! but I am facing another issue , that is after clicking on the icon, a new icon is created with attached classes rather than changing the classes of existing icon. I guess something wrong with my reference to the element.

Comment: If you know the class names in advance, rather use `@HostBinding()` than `renderer.setElementClass`. The `Renderer` generally only provides methods to set stuff but not to read stuff. Changing would also require to remove, which doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: still the same result as the earlier solution

Comment: Can you please explain what behavior you expect ecactly?

Comment: The code in your question and in my answer adds the classes to the `<courses></courses>` element, not to the `<i>` element. Maybe my updated example (**update2**) is what you're looking for.

Comment: I see. If you inject `ElementRef` this element refers the host element of your component (`<courses>`). `@HostBinding()` also affects the host element. If you want to update classes on elements in the template of a component you can use `[ngClass]="stringListOfStringOrObject"` or `[class.className]="booleanValue"` to make shown classes dependent of the model. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/35231503/217408 and https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/NgClass-directive.html