# How to add classes to host in angular 2?

Tags: angular, class-names

I need to add a class attribute dinamically the a host component made with Angular 2.

What I want to do isn't this way:
[How to add "class" to host element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641281/how-to-add-class-to-host-element)

In the case above it would be necessary the hardcoding of the class. My objective is to add a unknown class, at compile time, received as a string by parameter or something like.

I need to inject the class from inside Angular 2, not define it as an attribute. It also should not avoid to pass another classes by parameter. I also would like to avoid handle the native dom.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37643331/setelementclass-for-multiple-classes-in-angular2/37643364#37643364

Answer (score 3):

Use [Renderer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html):

```
// Renderer.setElementClass(renderElement: any, className: string, isAdd: boolean) : any

class MyComponent {
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.renderer.setElementClass(this.elRef.nativeElement, "whatever", true || false)
  }
}
```